# Component Object Model Query Interace

Tags: c++, com

Hi I am reading Don Box's book "Essential COM". My question is regarding the QueryInterface method in the IUnknown. Although I understand that the implementation for typecasting is moved to the interface to shield client from the type casting code, I dont understand the reason for this. The book says in the first chapter that the implementation for RTTI vary from compiler to compiler, hence the motivation for having QueryInterface method in the IUnknown. However what is wrong with doing the casting on client side. I mean it is only required that the implementation be cross vendor, cross compiler and cross platform, the client code doesnt have to have any of these constraints and hence casting could have been done on client side as well. Any insight into this would be appreciated.

Thanks, 
Abdul

Answer (score 0):

A cast in the presence of multiple inheritance requires knowledge of the implementation, so it can't be purely client-side. (What is needed is pretty much a dynamic cast.)

The existing mechanism also allows for useful implementation techniques that casting wouldn't - for example the result of QueryInterface can be an entirely separate object, perhaps created on the fly.